# Opensuse failed to start sound service

Tags: linux, audio, opensuse

My laptop's audio stopped working. Checking the log I find the error `failed to start sound service`, but I am not sure what to check.

I use Linux Opensuse 15.2

"journalctl" command show this:

[image]

and "dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn" show this:
[image]

Ajunto el archivo [/etc/pulse/default.pa](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zwx1ABzxu1pg3ufX-1IrIz8k4V8YkjSs/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to /etc/pulse/default.pa with

```
nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

change

```
!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
```

Then run

```
pulseaudio -D
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you. What I don't understand is why the file changed by itself.

Comment: I actually work at SUSE (well, haven't started yet) and I don't know :P maybe there was an update...?